# SQL Server: Is it possible to log errors of statements or a transactions using Extended Events?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I'm logging many things via Extended Events. I saw the `error_reported` or `errorlog_written` is very generic and logs a lot of errors.

With Extended Events, is it possible to get an SQL transaction or statement error?

I'd like to get the log using Extended Events if a SQL of INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE or other returns an error.

Is it possible?

Comment: Depending on the severity it’d be logged by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good article:

https://dbafromthecold.com/2017/06/07/identifying-failed-queries-with-extended-events/

I think the answer is to use error_reported with severity = 15 with says:
Indicates syntax errors in the Transact-SQL command.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-2017